# shift key and left mouse click in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make shift key and left mouse click in my angular 2 project.

```
    @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
     keyboardInput(event: KeyboardEvent) {
     if(event.shiftKey && event.which === 1){
       console.log("shiftkey+left mouse");
}
```

it's not work.

Comment: It should work, check [demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Aubybjbkp7p8FPxqM0zx?p=preview)

Comment: yes but I want shift key and right mouse click together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this,it works,

```
 @Component({
        selector: 'xxxx',
        templateUrl: 'yourtemplate',
        host: {
            '(window:keydown)': 'findKey($event)',
            '(window:mousedown)': 'findKey($event)'
        }
    });

    findKey(event) {
             if(event.shiftKey && event.which === 1){
                   console.log("shiftkey+left mouse");
            }
        }
```

Comment: If it is the right mouse that you want then, event.shiftKey && event.which === 3

Comment: what to write in template? (mouseup)? (keypress)=findkey($event)? because it throws me an execption: Error in :0:0 caused by: self.context.findKey is not a function

Comment: when `mousedown` event will fire `event.shiftKey` will not be true, as `mouseDown` only understands `mouse` events

Comment: Why do you need to write in template? This is for window shift key and left mouse click right?

Comment: Both happens simultaneously go I guess both were true and I was able to get this in the console. You can try this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    onClick( e: MouseEvent ) {
        if(e.button == 0 && e.shiftKey){
            console.log('we are in click and shift')
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).